# Windows Phone Application Bar TextBox

Tags: textbox, windows-phone, application-bar

I was wondering, if it is somehow possible to add a TextBox in the Application Bar area (the same way the Internet Explorer does), but I didn't find any information source about this. Have you any idea, how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to add UIElements inside ApplicationBar as it is not derived from UIElement.

Alternatively, you can try adding a Grid at the bottom of the screen and color it similar to the ApplicationBar. Then add a TextBlock inside the Grid. This is just a workaround and not recommended as it is not according to the standards.

You can also check the following link:
http://www.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/10/bindable-application-bar-extensions-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: IE for windows phone 8.1 has somehow included a textbox within application bar?