# make button clickable when the application bar is open

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, application-bar

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975315/windows-phone-application-bar-textbox) question. I prepare `stack panel` with 4 `textboxes` and `button`. When the user open `application bar` i change the `margin` in `stackpanel` to fit it to the top of `application bar` and here is the problem.

If the `application bar` is open and I try to click on the `button` which is on the `stackpanel`, instead of invoking the click event, the `application bar` became closed. The code from click event isn't invoked at all.

Here is my code in xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="SummerizePanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource StackPanelStyle1}">

        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="pay:" Foreground="Black" />
            <TextBlock Text="0.0  " x:Name="payment" FontSize="40"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 0 0 0" >
            <TextBlock Text="how:" Foreground="Black" />
            <TextBlock Text="0" FontSize="40" x:Name="acc"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button
            Margin="30 0 0 0" Width="167"  Background="Black" Click="GoToCheckout_Click"  Content="Go there">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar >
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="option_bar" StateChanged="ApplicationBar_StateChanged"  BackgroundColor="#FFCB0505" Mode="Minimized"  Opacity="1" >
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems  >                
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Kupony"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="My account" Click="Update_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Log out" Click="logout_Click"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Is there any possibility to make it clickable when the application bar is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding after `StateChanged="ApplicationBar_StateChanged"`:

```
Click="Click_Show"
```

And in code in the function Click_Show change the desired button options